# How to show soft-keyboard when edittext is focused

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-input-method

I know their are 100 posts about this one, and somehow it isn't working for me.
I got an EditText, and when I "touch" that box, the keyboard must appear.

This is everything I tried already:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
             EditText Edit_perceel_nr2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Perceel_nr2);;
             InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
             imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Edit_perceel_nr2.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

and

```
public void onClick(View v) {
             EditText Edit_perceel_nr2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Perceel_nr2);;
             InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
             imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Edit_perceel_nr2.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

and

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

             EditText Edit_perceel_nr2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Perceel_nr2);;
             ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(Edit_perceel_nr2, 0);
```

and

```
public void onClick(View v) {

             EditText Edit_perceel_nr2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Perceel_nr2);;
             ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(Edit_perceel_nr2, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

I even tried to add this in the manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

But I can't get it to work.
Probably I forgot something, but I am out of ideas now.
Someone got more ideas or the solution?

This is my edittext:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Perceel_nr2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="text"> 
</EditText>
```

Comment: As far as i know you don't need to do anything to show the keyboard. just add your EditText and don't set onClick for it!

Comment: Oh, no that onClick is for a button, when I hit a button, then he must do some actions, and this is one of it.

Comment: How are you creating your edittext?

Comment: check this [link][1] for keyPad open when on editText click


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7009155/3392323

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this..

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

To Close u can use

```
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Ah, I am blind -.-, I used `hideSoftInputFromWindow` instead of `showSoftInputFromWindow`, I was looking at this problem for 3 hours already (time for coffee?)

Comment: I deleted the `InputMethodManager` now, and somehow it works now also without the forced keyboard show code...